# Deep Freeze can't be removed

Tags: windows-xp, deep-freeze

I have already installed Deep Freeze and now I cannot see its icon in taskbar. It's hidden
now; I can't thaw it and remove it.

Answer (score 4):

You need the **original setup file (exe)** to remove Deep Freeze. Run that file and choose the uninstall option.

This web page has also useful info about your problem: [How to Remove Faronics Deep Freeze 6 in Three Different Ways.](http://www.out-of-warranty.com/how-to-uninstall-faronics-deep-freeze-in-three-different-ways/)

Answer (score 0):

As Mehper noted you can use the installer to remove Deep Freeze - however if you're looking to manage it from the local computer you can hit the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> to bring up the settings window.